# Secure communication between Ingress Controller (Traefik) and backend service on Kubernetes

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, apache-nifi, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to secure Nifi in a Kubernetes cluster, behind a Traefik proxy. Both are running as services in K8S. Traefik is secured with a public certificate. I want it to redirect calls to nifi, while securing the communication between Traefik (as an Ingress Controller) and the backend pods : Nifi.

Looks like the secure confiuration should lire in my Ingress YAML descriptor. Looks like I should issue a CA root to generate Nifi self signed certificate and load this CA Root in Traefik so it can validate the certificate sent by Nifi while handshaking with it.

But... I can't figure out 1) if this is the good approach, 2) how I can generate my stores (trust, ...) for NiFi using a CA Root, 3) how I should setup my YAML (`insecureSkipVerify` seems not to be supported, ...)

By advance, thanks for you help.

Cheers,

Olivier

Comment: I'm not familiar with traefik or Ingress Controllers, but for Apache NiFi, you can use the included `tls-toolkit` to generate a local CA, generate and sign as many node and client certificates as you want, and put them all into secured JKS keystores and truststores for easy deployment. A [guide is available here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#tls-generation-toolkit).

Comment: Yes, thank you @Andy but this does not solve the problem. I (of course) use NiFi `tls-toolkit` but this generates self-signed certificates. So I need to accept this certificate in Traefik/Ingress. And I can't figure out how to do this in K8S.

Comment: You can generate certificates signed by an external entity for NiFi or you can use the NiFi self-signed CA certificate and import it into the Traefik truststore. I don’t know for sure but I would look in the traefik.yaml file to see if there is a configuration value for an external truststore, or if it identifies the existing truststore file you need to import the CA public certificate into.

Comment: @Olivier Did you make any progress? I'm stuck with the same problem. In NiFi I get a `bad_certificate` exception during handshake.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve it with the `insecureSkipVerify` flag.
The problem with traefik is, that NiFi gets the request from traefik and sends it's self signed certificate back to traefik for hand shaking. Traefik doesn't accept it, thus the handshake fails, leading to a `bad_certificate` exception in NiFi (has loglevel `DEBUG`, so you have to change the `logback.xml` file).

So one solution could be to add your self signed certificate to traefik, which is not possible at the moment, [see this (currently) open issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3038).

Another solution, without 'insecuring' your existing traefik would be to add an `nginx` between traefik and NiFi. So traefik talk `HTTP` with nginx, which talks `HTTPS` with NiFi (this will be the next thing I'm trying).

Or you can set the `insecureSkipVerify` flag within traefik like I did in this `daemonset.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-06-21T16:18:46Z
  generation: 4
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-internal
    release: infrastructure
  name: traefik-internal
  namespace: infrastructure
  resourceVersion: "18860064"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/infrastructure/daemonsets/traefik-internal
  uid: c64a20e1-776e-11f8-be83-42010a9c0ff6
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-internal
      name: traefik-internal
      release: infrastructure
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-internal
        name: traefik-internal
        release: infrastructure
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --api
        - --ping
        - --defaultEntryPoints=http,https
        - --logLevel=INFO
        - --accessLog
        - --kubernetes
        - --kubernetes.ingressClass=traefik-internal
        - --metrics.prometheus=true
        - --entryPoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS:/certs/cert.pem,/certs/cert.key
          CA:/certs/clientca.pem
        - --entryPoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
        - --insecureSkipVerify=true
        image: traefik:1.6.0-rc6-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: traefik-internal
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /certs
          name: traefik-internal-certs
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: sa-traefik
      serviceAccountName: sa-traefik
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      volumes:
      - name: traefik-internal-certs
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: traefik-internal
  templateGeneration: 4
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
status:
  currentNumberScheduled: 3
  desiredNumberScheduled: 3
  numberAvailable: 3
  numberMisscheduled: 0
  numberReady: 3
  observedGeneration: 4
  updatedNumberScheduled: 3
```

The `insecureSkipVerify` flag is changed within `spec.containers.args`.

Hope that helps!