# Secure traffic between kubernetes ingress and service

Tags: service, https, kubernetes, communication

I'm pretty new to kubernetes, I hope to explain myself in a good way, and if anyone has any resources/suggestions to read for my problem it would be really much appreciated.
Let's get straight to the point.
The web app I'm trying to expose accepts only https connection on the service. So basically I would like to ask the ingress to communicate with my service through https

Following some tutorial I tried to expose a simple web app(that accept http connection) through https, craeting a certificate and a secret and adding the following line to the ingress.yml:

```
 tls:
   - secretName: testexample.com
     hosts:
       - testexample.com
```

and executing a `curl -k https://testexample.com` or through browser I can see my webpage.
The troubles pops out when my webapp accept only https connection, and the webapp we are moving to kubernetes does.
I always receive "404 default backend" message.

I tried to look for some resources/tutorial/previous questions,

[Secure communication between Ingress Controller (Traefik) and backend service on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817014/secure-communication-between-ingress-controller-traefik-and-backend-service-on)

[Securing connections from ingress to services in Kubernetes with TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851049/securing-connections-from-ingress-to-services-in-kubernetes-with-tls)

but I didnt figure out how to get out of the problem.

Any suggestions as mentioned before would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your post with ingress and service yamls?

Answer (score 0):

Error source can are probably your Ingress rule. It's their not pointing to the correct service & port or it is not in the same namespace as the service.

Comment: Hi tomaaron, thanks for the answer.
Ingress and service are in the same namespace.
I can ping the ingress hostname, so the dns is able to resolve it, and checking the logs it looks like is exposed correctly.
There is the port left, my app is exposed on the container on port 8443, but I think the ingress will forward the traffic to the service not straight to the container.

Comment: You have to distinguish between the Ingress controller and it's rules. It also depends on how you expose the service. Can you share your service and Ingress rule definition?

Comment: Hi Tomaaron, here is my service

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-no-nfs
  labels:
    app: admin-no-nfs
spec:
  ports:
    - name : https
      port: 8443
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: admin-no-nfs

Comment: Here is my ingress ruels:

- host: <hostname>.domain
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
         serviceName: admin-no-nfs
         servicePort: 30407

Comment: Set the ingress rule servicePort to match with the service port of admin-no-nfs (8443).